# PHP download script returns download-file.php instead of filename

Tags: php, header, download

i wrote a download script that find a restricted file from server and after reading that, prepare the file for user to download it with the following headers.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Length: $filesize");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
```

but sometimes with default browsers download managers, it returns **download-file.php** instead of filename!

for example it should return `abc.zip` but it returns `download-file.php` and download process works perfectly

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you check the header response if there is always a filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't know how you're using `$file` or `$filesize` try this instead:

```
$file = "abc.zip"; // adjust accordingly
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
@readfile($file);
exit();
```

plus, a missing `readfile()`

This line:

```
header("Content-Length: $filesize");
```

should read as:

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file)); // or $filesize in your case.
```

Missing `filesize()`

Comment: thank you very much. can u explain differnces to me a little bit more?

Comment: You're very much welcome Mohammad. It was missing a few things as written in my answer, being `filesize()` and `readfile()` @MohammadMasoudian - those 2 functions are required.

Comment: i had those functions in my script but i wrote just a part of code because i thought that the headers have some problem!