# Firefox downloads retrieve.php instead of filename given per Content-Disposition header

Tags: php, download, header

I have a PHP script called retrieve.php that compresses uploaded files from a directory in to a .zip file and then outputs them to the stream, so said file can be downloaded.

The script works in all browsers except Firefox.
After searching online for quite a while now and coming across this question: [PHP download script returns download-file.php instead of filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226197/php-download-script-returns-download-file-php-instead-of-filename) and still having the same issue, I'm stumped and have no clue what's going wrong.

This is the code being used to download the file:

```
if ($zippedElements >= 1) {
//      die($zipFilename);
        $zipFilename = "download-".time().".zip";
        // Send zip to recipient
        header("Content-Dispositon: attachment; filename=\"$zipFilename\"");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zipFileName));
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        readfile($zipFileName);

    } else return;
```

I've tried setting the header to different values, such as content-type: application/force-download, adding the asterisk (*) after filename, etc., but all to no avail.

The result in Firefox looks as follows:

[image]

Any help with the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistencies in the variable name $zipFilename - the **N** is uppercased sometimes.

```
    $zipFilename = __FILE__;
    // Send zip to recipient
    header("Content-Dispositon: attachment; filename=\"$zipFilename\"");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zipFilename));
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    readfile($zipFilename);
```

Comment: Yes, that was on purpose. Should have added that. 
I solved the issue differently; I added another Content-Disposition header containing only the file name. For some reason both Firefox and all other browsers seem to like that, although it would seem the standard says the attachment or inline portion should always be passed.